# No reconoce mi base de datos phpmyadmin y mysql

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

**estoy enlazando mi base de datos que esta en mysql con php pero no me reconoce la base de datos , como si no la hubiera creado , cual es el error? estoy utilizando php para unirla.El servidor que estoy utilizando es xampp**

```
<?php

class Database{

    private $dbhost ='127.0.0.1';
    private $dbname ='escuela';
    private $username ='root';
    private $password ='';
    private $charset ='utf8mb4';

    function connect(){

        try{

            $conexion= "mysql:host=" . $this->dbhost . ";dbname=" . $this->dbname . ",charset=" . $this->charset;

            $options=[
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
            ];

             $pdo = new PDO($conexion, $this->username,$this->password,$options);

             return $pdo;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print_r('Error de conexion: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    }

?>
```

**esta es la conexión**

```
<?php

include_once 'database.php';

$db = new Database();

$db->connect();
        
?>
```

**me da este error**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**esta es la base de datos en mysql**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Además, cuando hayas resuelto el error que indica @BetaM te va a hacer falta una referencia explícita `use PDO` en las primeras líneas del archivo. Aunque PDO esté integrado necesita la referencia para ser usado. Ubicala antes de class Database

Comment: Gracias por la observación @BetaM desde que me estrellé con la necesidad lo asumí como regla

Comment: @BetaM  gracias por su ayuda amigo :,)

Comment: @quevedo gracias por su ayuda